# C++ CLion giving different sizes for containers?

Tags: c++, clion

I noticed that CLion often gives incorrect sizes for containers when using the debugging feature. Here, it says the size of `reach_sats` (an `unordered_map<int, deque<int>>`) has size 255 when it actually has size 1000 (confirmed when printed out). Anyone know what's up with this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't add pictures of text to your question. Edit the question and add the text.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal and typical for a variable to gain storage before it is initialised. Debuggers typically list variables as soon and as long as they have storage. If the variable hasn't been initialised, then it may appear to have a meaningless value in the debugger. With optimisation enabled, a variable might remain entirely uninitialised if it is never needed. This is normal.